# Error with Yahtzee Code: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, object-oriented-database

This is my code for finding the probability of different die cases in Yahtzee. I've figured out the yahtzee, and full house methods. But when I do the is_it_large_straight method it gives me an error of this:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

What do I need to change in my code to make it produce what I want it to?

```
import numpy as np
import random

class Die:

    def __init__(self, sides):
        """A constructor method to create a die"""
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        """A general method to roll the die"""
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)
```

## -------------------------------------------------

```
class Yahtzee:

    def __init__(self):
        """A constructor method that can record 5 dice rolls"""
        self.rolls = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.int16)

    def roll_dice(self):
        """A general method that rolls 5 dice"""
        for i in range(len(self.rolls)):
            self.rolls[i] = Die(6).roll()

    def count_outcomes(self):
        """A helper method that determines how many 1s, 2s, etc. were rolled"""
        counts = np.zeros(7, dtype=np.int16)
        for roll in self.rolls:
            counts[roll] += 1
        return counts
    def is_it_yahtzee(self):
        yahtzeefun = self.count_outcomes()
        if 5 in yahtzeefun:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def is_it_full_house(self):
        fullhouse = self.count_outcomes()
        if 2 in fullhouse and 3 in fullhouse:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def is_it_large_straight(self):
        largestraight = self.count_outcomes()
        if largestraight == [0,0,1,1,1,1,1] or largestraight == [0,1,1,1,1,1,0]:
            print("recognize straight")
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

## -------------------------------------------------

```
def main(how_many):

    yahtzees = 0
    full_houses = 0
    large_straights = 0
    game = Yahtzee()

    for i in range(how_many):
        game.roll_dice()
        if game.is_it_yahtzee():
            yahtzees += 1
        elif game.is_it_full_house():
            full_houses += 1
        elif game.is_it_large_straight():
            large_straights += 1

    print("Number of Rolls:", how_many)
    print("---------------------")
    print("Number of Yahtzees:", yahtzees)
    print("Yahtzee Percent:", "{:.2f}%\n".format(yahtzees * 100 / how_many))
    print("Number of Full Houses:", full_houses)
    print("Full House Percent:", "{:.2f}%\n".format(full_houses * 100 / how_many))
    print("Number of Large Straights:", large_straights)
    print("Large Straight Percent:", "{:.2f}%".format(large_straights * 100 / how_many))

# -------------------------------------------------

main(5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In is_it_large_straight replace

```
largestraight = self.count_outcomes()
```

with

```
largestraight = self.count_outcomes().tolist()
```

currently largestraight is a numpy array and it doesn't have a definite boolean value, and thus can't be compared to your list in largestraight == [0,0,1,1,1,1,1]